# How can this summation be proven to be equal?

Tags: calculus, summation

I have a problem understanding how the following two sides of the Equation can be proven to be Equal to eachother.

$$-\frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)-(u_j-u_{j-1})]v_j= \frac{1}{h}\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)(v_{j+1}-v_j)]$$

The tips I am given is to use summation by parts twice. The summation by parts is as follows: $\sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_j=u_{n+1}v_{n+1}-u_0v_0-\sum_{j=0}^{n} (v_{j+1}-v_j)u_{j+1}$. It is also given that $v_{n+1}=u_{n+1}=u_0=v_0=u_{-1}=v_{-1}=0$. I have tried doing this in many ways, but I do not manage to go from one of the sides of the Equation to the other. I hope someone can help me doing that.
David

Comment: The symbol $v$ (without subscript) occurs just once. What is it?

Comment: u and v are just two different functions.

Comment: A function of what? On the right-hand side of your equation to be proven, all your $v$s have subscripts. On the left-hand side there is just a single $v$ and _it has no subscript_. We have no way to relate it to any other thing that is mentioned anywhere in the problem statement.

Comment: u and v are eigenfunctions, but it does not say anything more about it in the book. We are supposed to use the summation by part Expression, to prove that the the left side of the Equation can be written in the form of the right hand side of the Equation, but I don't manage to do it.

Comment: You are missing my point. Look at your equation carefully. What is the subscript of $v$ on the left-hand side of the equation?

Comment: I am sorry, now I understand Your question. The v has subscript j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify by multiplying both sides by $h$.

Then I suggest rewriting the left side of the equation you are to prove, using this idea:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)-(u_j-u_{j-1})]v_j
= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_j - \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_j-u_{j-1})v_j.$$

Now you have things that look a little like summation of parts.
You can split the right-hand side in two parts like this in two different ways:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)(v_{j+1}-v_j)]
= \sum_{j=0}^{n} u_{j+1}(v_{j+1}-v_j) - \sum_{j=0}^{n} u_j(v_{j+1}-v_j)$$
or
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)(v_{j+1}-v_j)]
= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_{j+1} - \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_j.$$

I think you will find one of those approaches fits the problem better than the other.

---

An alternative approach is to observe that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_j-u_{j-1})v_j =  \sum_{j=-1}^{n-1} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_{j+1},$$
so the left-hand side of your equation can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} [(u_{j+1}-u_j)-(u_j-u_{j-1})]v_j
= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_j - \sum_{j=-1}^{n-1} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_{j+1}.$$

If you can just show that
$$\sum_{j=-1}^{n-1} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_{j+1} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} (u_{j+1}-u_j)v_{j+1}$$
then you don't need to invoke summation by parts.
This last equation is not true for all functions $u_i$ and $v_i$, of course, but
your functions are known to have values for certain values of the subscript,
and these values are helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Write $\Delta u_j$ for $u_{j+1}-u_j$, and multiply through by $h$; then you’re being asked to show that

$$-\sum_{j=0}^n(\Delta u_j-\Delta u_{j-1})v_j=\sum_{j=0}^n\Delta u_j\Delta v_j\;.$$

The summation by parts formula for sequences with terms $f_k$ and $g_k$ as I would write it (following Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*) is

$${\sum}_a^bf_k\Delta g_k=[f_kg_k]_a^b-{\sum}_a^bEg_k\Delta f_k\;,$$

where $Eg_k=g_{k+1}$, and $$\sum_a^bx_k=\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}x_k\;.$$

That notation emphasizes the parallel with integration by parts. In more familiar notation it’s

$$\sum_{k=a}^bf_k\Delta g_k=f_{b+1}g_{b+1}-f_ag_a-\sum_{k=a}^bg_{k+1}\Delta f_k\;,$$

or, equivalently,

$$\sum_{k=a}^bg_{k+1}\Delta f_k=f_{b+1}g_{b+1}-f_ag_a-\sum_{k=a}^bf_k\Delta g_k\;.$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n(\Delta u_j-\Delta u_{j-1})v_j&=\sum_{j=0}^n\Delta(\Delta u_{j-1})v_j\\
&=\sum_{j=-1}^{n-1}v_{j+1}\Delta(\Delta u_j)\\
&=v_n\Delta u_n-v_{-1}\Delta u_{-1}-\sum_{j=-1}^{n-1}\Delta u_j\Delta v_j\\
&=v_n\Delta u_n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\Delta u_j\Delta v_j\\
&=-\Delta v_n\Delta u_n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\Delta u_j\Delta v_j\\
&=-\sum_{j=0}^n\Delta u_j\Delta v_j\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last three steps make use of the hypothesis that $$v_{n+1}=u_{n+1}=u_0=v_0=u_{-1}=v_{-1}=0\;.$$

Comment: This was also a very Nice way to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @David: You’re welcome!